# How I print this even number as a array like: [4 8 2 ]

Tags: javascript

This is a simple JavaScript code of print even number, but I want the output result as a array : [4 8 2]

```
var arr = [4, 8, 5, 9, 3, 7, 2]
for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]%2==0){
        console.log(arr[i])
    }
}
Output:
4
8
2
```

Comment: What about, in the if statement add them to an output array and after the loop log the array?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: What is keeping you from putting the even numbers into an array?

Comment: use filter like this: `let evens = arr.filter(i => i % 2 ===0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new result `array`. Then add values into `array` inside your `if` condition via `push()` method. Refer the below code :

```js
var arr = [4, 8, 5, 9, 3, 7, 2]
var res = [];
for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]%2==0){
        res.push(arr[i]);
    }
}

console.log(res)
```